# Handling unexpected exceptions on Gtk 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk, gtk3

I have an application made in python with Gtk. The Gtk has a main loop. like bellow:

```
gtk.main()
```

When an unexpected error occurs, the value is printed in the python log and the Gtk ignores the error, but what I need is that this message to appear to the end user. How can I get this exceptions in Gtk?

Comment: What types of errors,  Tracebacks or Gtk warnings?

Comment: Tracebacks, @zondo